# How to split a running solr cloud shard base on field?

Tags: solr, sharding, solrcloud

I have a solr cloud 7.6.0 cluster running with 1 shard. The shard is growing quite fast so I'm going split it into separated shards base on `"brand"` field. For example:

Docs in current shards (Shard1, Collection1):

```
doc1: {"id":"doc1","brand":"brand1"}
doc2: {"id":"doc2","brand":"brand1"}
doc3: {"id":"doc3","brand":"brand2"}
doc4: {"id":"doc3","brand":"brand2"}
```

How could I split them into `shard1_0 (doc1, doc2), shard1_1 (doc3, doc4)`?

Comment: If you want to shard by a specific brand, that brand should probably be made part of your `id` so you can use the `_route_` parameter, as well as use `split.key` when splitting the shards. I'm not familiar with any way to split the shards without considering the unique key (and just a sub field such as `brand`).

Comment: Thank you. I worked out a work around solution by creating new shard and re-index.